# JavaFX: Trying to get my buttons to correspond with the .css

Tags: java, css, javafx

Overall, css seems to be working for everything but the buttons. I originally had this all in FXML but was told to switch it to straight JavaFX. Trying to get my buttons to follow their css again.

Is there a way to set button IDs in FX?

Any help would be appreciated, I've done a lot of looking through the documentation and some tutorials, but haven't been able to figure it out.

Here is my button code:

```java
public class MainViewController extends Application {

    private Button getStarted, getLoad, getHelp, returnToStart;
    private TextArea tips;
    private Pane mainPane, storyPane, helpPane;
    

    public MainViewController() {
        getStarted = new Button("S T A R T");
        getLoad = new Button("L O  A D");
        getHelp = new Button("H E L P");
        returnToStart = new Button("R T R N");
        tips = new TextArea();
        mainPane = new Pane();
        storyPane = new Pane();
        helpPane = new Pane();
        
    
        //Main Pane Layouts
        getStarted.setLayoutX(370);
        getStarted.setLayoutY(164);
        getStarted.setPrefHeight(35);
        getStarted.setPrefWidth(110);
        getStarted.getStyleClass().add("resources/css/MainView.css");

        getLoad.setLayoutX(370);
        getLoad.setLayoutY(215);
        getLoad.setPrefHeight(35);
        getLoad.setPrefWidth(110);
        getLoad.getStyleClass().add("resources/css/MainView.css");

        getHelp.setLayoutX(370);
        getHelp.setLayoutY(266);
        getHelp.setPrefHeight(35);
        getHelp.setPrefWidth(110);
        getHelp.getStyleClass().add("resources/css/MainView.css");

        mainPane.getChildren().addAll(getStarted, getLoad, getHelp);
        
        //Help Pane Layouts
        returnToStart.setLayoutX(356);
        returnToStart.setLayoutY(266);
        returnToStart.setPrefHeight(35);
        returnToStart.setPrefWidth(110);
        
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        
        Scene mainView = new Scene(mainPane, 488, 322);
        stage.setScene(mainView);
        mainView.getStylesheets().add("resources/css/MainView.css");
        stage.setTitle("Return to Monke");
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.getIcons().add(new Image("resources/images/monke_icon.png"));
        stage.show();
        Media opening = new Media(new File("src/resources/files/Opening.mp3").toURI().toString()); 
        MediaPlayer openPlay = new MediaPlayer(opening);
        openPlay.play();
        openPlay.setCycleCount(MediaPlayer.INDEFINITE);
        openPlay.setAutoPlay(true);
        Media story = new Media(new File("src/resources/files/insert.mp3").toURI().toString());
        MediaPlayer storyPlay = new MediaPlayer(story);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Here is my css:

````
.root {
    -fx-background-image: url("../images/rtm.gif");
    -fx-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -fx-fill-width: 50%;
    -fx-fill-heigt: 50%;
}


#Button {
    -fx-font-family: "Roboto";
    -fx-text-fill: black;
    -fx-padding: 8 15 15 15;
    -fx-background-insets: 0,0 0 5 0, 0 0 6 0, 0 0 7 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 10;
    -fx-background-color:
            linear-gradient(from 0% 93% to 0% 100%, #9922a3 0%, #903482 100%),
            #9d0096,
            #c609d8,
            radial-gradient(center 50% 50%, radius 100%, #a31e9d, #cb21a8);
    -fx-effect: dropshadow( gaussian , rgba(0,0,0,0.75) , 4,0,0,1 );
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
    -fx-font-size: 1.1em;
    -fx-opacity: 0.6;
}
#Button:hover {
    -fx-background-color:
            linear-gradient(from 0% 93% to 0% 100%, #903482 0%, #9922a3 100%),
            #9d0096,
            #c609d8,
            radial-gradient(center 50% 50%, radius 100%, #d538bb, #c52da5);
}
#Button:pressed {
    -fx-padding: 10 15 13 15;
    -fx-background-insets: 2 0 0 0,2 0 3 0, 2 0 4 0, 2 0 5 0;
}
#Button Text {
    -fx-fill: white;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(gaussian, #a30000, 0, 0, 0, 2);
}

#Load {
    -fx-font-family: "Roboto";
    -fx-text-fill: black;
    -fx-padding: 8 15 15 15;
    -fx-background-insets: 0,0 0 5 0, 0 0 6 0, 0 0 7 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 10;
    -fx-background-color:
            linear-gradient(from 0% 93% to 0% 100%, #0AFA18 0%, #00CD0C 100%),
            #019B0A,
            #7AFF81,
            radial-gradient(center 50% 50%, radius 100%, #0AFA18, #00CD0C);
    -fx-effect: dropshadow( gaussian , rgba(0,0,0,0.75) , 4,0,0,1 );
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
    -fx-font-size: 1.1em;
    -fx-opacity: 0.6;
}
#Load:hover {
    -fx-background-color:
            linear-gradient(from 0% 93% to 0% 100%, #9FFF84 0%, #81D26A 100%),
            #60A54C,
            #60A54C,
            radial-gradient(center 50% 50%, radius 100%, #9FFF84, #60A54C);
}
#Load:pressed {
    -fx-padding: 10 15 13 15;
    -fx-background-insets: 2 0 0 0,2 0 3 0, 2 0 4 0, 2 0 5 0;
}
#Load Text {
    -fx-fill: white;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(gaussian, #a30000, 0, 0, 0, 2);
}

#Help {
    -fx-font-family: "Roboto";
    -fx-text-fill: black;
    -fx-padding: 8 15 15 15;
    -fx-background-insets: 0,0 0 5 0, 0 0 6 0, 0 0 7 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 10;
    -fx-background-color:
            linear-gradient(from 0% 93% to 0% 100%, #0086FC 0%, #0073D7 100%),
            #0060B4,
            #0060B4,
            radial-gradient(center 50% 50%, radius 100%, #0086FC, #0060B4);
    -fx-effect: dropshadow( gaussian , rgba(0,0,0,0.75) , 4,0,0,1 );
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
    -fx-font-size: 1.1em;
    -fx-opacity: 0.6;
}
#Help:hover {
    -fx-background-color:
            linear-gradient(from 0% 93% to 0% 100%, #72BDFF 0%, #60A0D8 100%),
            #4F86B6,
           #4F86B6,
            radial-gradient(center 50% 50%, radius 100%, #72BDFF, #4F86B6);
}
#Help:pressed {
    -fx-padding: 10 15 13 15;
    -fx-background-insets: 2 0 0 0,2 0 3 0, 2 0 4 0, 2 0 5 0;
}
#Help Text {
    -fx-fill: white;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(gaussian, #a30000, 0, 0, 0, 2);
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.
It's getStyleClass("name of CSS button")